# How to remove some unknown sticky dirt from a window?

Tags: windows, cleaning

This happens on my car, but it could happen in any home window. Therefore, I post here.

My car has some unknown sticky dirt on the window. I have no clue what it is. I can remove some of the dirt by my finger nail but not completely. I tried to use wet paper towel but does not remove any at all.

Note: I took two pictures. One is from the inside of the car. The other one is from outside of the car.

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried just hot soapy water? Simple, cheap, effective, and least likely to damage anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell from just a photo, but tree sap often causes this kind of residue when dirt or dust gets into it.

To remove, try each one at a time until one works, in the following order:

1. Methanol
2. Ammonia
3. Paint thinner
4. Acetone *(be careful with this one on plastics)*

The first one is the least likely to damage your finish or plastics, the last the most likely.  If it's a modern car with a base coat/clear coat system, none of the above solvents should do the paint any harm, but the acetone could affect any finished or coated plastics.

Comment: Is your shift key broken?  Sentences are much easier to read when proper capitalization is used.

Comment: yes. shift key broken.  also, automatic grammar correction engine disabled due to catastrophic flux capacitor overload.  indenting drive might be next...

Answer (score 3):

If it's on the window glass the simplest way to remove any foreign substance  without the risk of harsh chemicals , is with a single edged razor blade. If you install the blade in a retractable holder you can extend the reach of the blade. Hold the blade at a 25-40 degree angle.